# JAVA- variable distinta a un caracter o string

Tags: java

el programa que intento hacer es decir si un numero es primo o no , y al introducir el usuario el numero tengo que decir si es valido o no es decir menor que 0 es un valor no valido  y si introduce una letra o cualquier caracter me diga que no es correcto .
supongamos que num1 es el numero que introduce el usuario , tengo todo menos comprobar si es una letra lo que introduce.

```
if (num1 <= 0 || ) {
        do {
            System.out.println(num1 + " no es un valor válido, introduce un valor válido");
            num1 = scanner.nextInt();

        } while (num1 <= 0);

    }
    if (num1 >= 0) {
        System.out.println(num1 + " es un valor válido");
    }
```

Comment: no sé cómo funciona scanner directamente, pero si pides un int, supongo que puede haber alguna excepción o algo para cuando metes algo que no es

Comment: revisa el método HasNextInt(). Fuente: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-nextint-method-in-java-with-examples/

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo usar un try catch

Creo que este es el metodo mas sencillo para hacer.
El try catch es un metodo para **atrapar** excepciones, pues, habrás notado que cuando uno ingresa una letra cuando pide un nextInt, el programa se cierra por una expecion, bueno, con este metodo hacemos que el programa no se caiga, si no que lo "intenta", y te avisa si ocurre un error.

```
    int num1; 
    System.out.println("Ingrese un numero");
    try{ //el programa intentara hacer todo lo que esta adentro
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        num1 = scanner.nextInt(); //
        scanner.nextLine();
        if(num1<0) System.out.println("El numero es menor a 0");
        else {
            System.out.println("Aqui va el procedimiento para saber si es primo");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){//esto es lo que pasa cuando se detecta un error
        System.out.println("Ingreso algo que no es un numero");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puede hacer manejando excepciones, la idea es leer el valor que ingresas por teclado y parsear a entero; si el valor ingresado por teclado no es número entonces arrojará una excepción, te dejo el código

```
private static boolean isNumeric(String cadena){
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(cadena);//convertir a entero el valor ingresado por teclado
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
                System.out.println("EL VALOR INGRESADO NO ES NÚMERO "+nfe);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hacemos uso del método creado de la siguiente forma, no pongo el código como se verifica si es un número primo porque no es parte de tu pregunta.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String numero;
        System.out.print("Introduce el número a verificar si es primo: ");       
        numero= sc.nextLine();
        do{
            if (isNumeric(numero)&&Integer.parseInt(numero)>0){//Verifica si es entero y mayor que 0
                //escribir tú código para verificar que sea un número primo
            }else{
            System.out.print("Introduce el número a verificar si es primo: ");       
            numero= sc.nextLine();
            }
            
        }while(!isNumeric(numero)||Integer.parseInt(numero)<=0);    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te pongo una forma más de resolverlo

El código es para el ejercicio completo, evalúa si es número y si es número primo

```
public class NumeroPrimo {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    
        //instanciamos la clase scanner
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        //pedimos un número
        System.out.println("Introduzca un número");
        //para no tener errores, cogemos ese número como un string
        String valor = teclado.nextLine();

        //llamamos al método esNumero y si devuelve true       
        if (esNumero(valor)){
            //convertimos el string en un int
            int numero = Integer.parseInt(valor);
            //llamamos al método esPrimo y guardamos el resultado en la variable booleana primo
            boolean primo = esPrimo(numero);
            //si primo es true
            if (primo == true){
                System.out.println("El número es primo");
            }
            //si primo no es true
            else{
                System.out.println("El número no es primo");
            }
        }
        //si no se introduce un número por teclado
        else{
            System.out.println("El número no es correcto");
        }
    }
    //método es Numero que recibe un string por parámetro
    public static boolean esNumero(String numero){
        //bucle que recorre el string carácter a carácter
        for (char c: numero.toCharArray()){
            //si entre todos los caracteres hay alguno distinto a número
            if (!Character.isDigit(c)){
                return false;
            }
        }
        //si todos los caracteres son números retorna true
        return true;
    }
    //metodo es primo
    public static boolean esPrimo(int numero) {
        // Los números 0, 1 y 4 no son primos, por lo tanto 
        if (numero == 0 || numero == 1 || numero == 4) {
            //retorna falso
            return false;
        }
        //hacemos un bucle
        for (int x = 2; x < numero / 2; x++) {
            // Si es divisible por cualquiera de estos números, no es primo
            if (numero % x == 0)
                return false;
        }
        // Si no se pudo dividir por ninguno de los de arriba, sí es primo
        return true;
    }
}
```