# Java clase Scanner

Tags: java

mi proyecto es el siguiente : quiero que el usuario introduzca un numero y luego decir si es primo o no , mi problema es que cuando mete un valor que no es un numero , mi programa peta y no se como arreglarlo , dejo aqui el trozo de codigo donde me da problemas.

```
public static boolean pedirNumero() {
    System.out.println("Introduce un numero para saber si es primo");
    guardar = scanner.hasNextInt(); 

    if (guardar == true) {
        guardar2 = scanner.nextInt();

    } else {
        do {
            System.out.println("Introduce un valor valido.");
            guardar = scanner.hasNextInt();
            guardar2 = scanner.nextInt();

        } while (guardar != true);
    }

    return guardar;

}
```

el error que me sale cuando introduzco algo que no es un numero es el siguiente:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at Main.pedirNumero(Main.java:43)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Comment: SUponemos que guardar es int?

Comment: Debería ser realmente un booleano por la condición if

Comment: guardar es boleano y guardar2 int

Comment: Al no tener los demás métodos que usar no puedo decirte que está mal, pero puedes revisar el siguiente enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/463872/193364 donde ya está respondido tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola @Joshin, en la pregunta que enlazas, L.Ronquillo, le sugiere investigar sobre el método hasNextInt(), y creo que es la duda que propone en ésta pregunta, pues ninguna de las respuestas de su otra pregunta se lo aclaraba, incluyendo la mía. Espero que ahora hayamos podido despejarle todas sus dudas. Un saludo

Comment: Por cierto @Kyle781227, ésta comunidad establece un grado de reputación en función de las interacciones que hemos tenido en la misma en base a preguntas y respuestas valoradas de forma positiva o negativa y respuestas aceptadas. En tu anterior pregunta tuviste tres respuestas, pero no has otrorgado  puntuación a ninguna de ellas, tampoco has aceptado como buena ninguna de las tres. Te recomiendo hacerlo, pues la gente que pueda molestarse en contestar, si no obtiene tu recompensa, dejará de hacerlo, yo entre ellos. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

En tu código, si no me equivoco:

```
//guardar coge el valor true si es lo introducido por teclado es un número
guardar = scanner.hasNextInt(); 

//En la condición entra sin problema funcionando correctamente
if (guardar == true) {
    //Sin embargo, la variable guardar2 ya no recibe el número de la clase scanner, por alguna razón, se valor ya no le llega
    guardar2 = scanner.nextInt();
```

La corrección que te sugiero, es, una vez pedido el número, evaluarlo directamente *if (scanner.hasNextInt())*, y si es número, pasarlo ahora a la variable. De esa forma si me ha funcionado. (El true no hace falta ponerlo, ya que en éste caso sería el valor por defecto)

También eliminé el bucle do - while para pasarlo a un método recursivo, mientras no se introduzca un valor numérico válido, el método se llamará a si mismo una y otro vez

Tenía duda si retornabas el valor booleano o el entero, yo retorno el entero, pero bueno, lo cambias a tu interés

```
public class PedirNumero{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //llamamos al método pedirNumero y almacenamos ese número en la variable guardar
        int guardar = pedirNumero();
    
        //imprimimos el número, pues ya vendrá validado del método
        System.out.println(guardar + " es un número");
    }
    public static int pedirNumero() {
        //declaramos una variable y la iniciamos a cero
        int guardar = 0;
        //instanciamos la clase scanner
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        //pedimos un número
        System.out.println("Introduce un numero para saber si es primo");

        //Si lo ingresado por teclado es número
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            //lo almacenamos en la variable guardar
            guardar = scanner.nextInt();
        } 
        else {
            //si no es número avisamos al usuario
            System.out.println("Introduce un valor valido.");
            //llamamos nuevamente al método
            pedirNumero();
        }
        //retornamos la variable guardar
        return guardar;
    }
}
```

Otra forma de validar la entrada el teclado sería:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    //declaramos un variable de tipo entero
    int numero = 0;
    //instanciamos la clase scanner
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    //pedimos algo por teclado
    System.out.println("Escriba lo que desee");
    //recogemos ese algo como texto
    String cadena = teclado.nextLine();
    
    //llamamos al metodo es numero y enviamos ese texto recogiendo el resultado en la variable booleana esNoes
    boolean esNoes = metodoEsNumero(cadena);

    //si la variable booleana es true, es número        
    if (esNoes == true){
        //imprimimos es un número
        System.out.println(cadena + " es un numero");
        //guardamos el texto como número en la variable número y lo tienes disponible para hacer con él lo que quieras
        numero = Integer.parseInt(cadena);
    }
    else{
        //si es false, imprime no es número
        System.out.println(cadena + " NO es un numero");
    }
}
public static boolean metodoEsNumero(String cadena){
    try {
            //convertimos la cadena del teclado a número
            Integer.parseInt(cadena);
            //si es número devuelve true
            return true;
    } 
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
            //si no es número producirá error y devolveremos false
            return false;
    }
}
```